# Unable to connect to virtual machine

Tags: google-compute-engine

Unable to connect to Virtual Machine via SSH. Http to VM also unavailable.
It worked for a long time, but yesterday(24.09.2020) it broke, i have do nothing on it at that time.
On SSH have error

```
Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed
Code: 4003
Reason: failed to connect to backend
You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.
```

I have tried:

- reboot
- upgrade WM instance capacity
- upgrade disk size
- check VPC config

Nothing is work.

Does anyone can suggest anything, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, try to disable Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy and connect to the VM instance via web Console.

Then, you should check logs:

- Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)`
- Reboot your VM instance.
- Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings.

If your VM instance doesn't start up verify that your disk has a valid file system and a valid master boot record (MBR) by following the documentation [General troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances).

If you found errors/warning related to disk space you can try to resize it accordingly to the documentation [Resizing a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd), also accordingly to the article [Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance):

> If an instance is completely out of disk space or if it is not running
> a Linux guest environment, then automatically resizing your root
> filesystem isn't possible, even after you've increased the size of the
> persistent disk that backs it. If you can't connect to your instance,
> or your boot disk is full and you can't resize it, you must create a
> new instance and recreate the boot disk from a snapshot to resize it.

Otherwise try get access to your VM instance via serial console :

- [Enable serial console connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access) with `gcloud` command:

  ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE
  ```

  or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and check `Enable connecting to serial ports`
- Create temporary user and password to login: shutdown your VM and set a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) by adding at the section **`Custom metadata`** key `startup-script` and value:

  ```
    #!/bin/bash
    useradd --groups google_sudoers tempuser
    echo "tempuser:password" | chpasswd
  ```

  and then start your VM.
- [Connect to your VM via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) with `gcloud` command:

  ```
    gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE
  ```

  or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> and click on `Connect to serial console`
- Check what went wrong.
- [Disable access via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#disable_access) with `gcloud` command:

  ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=FALSE
  ```

  or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and uncheck `Enable connecting to serial ports`. Keep in mind that accordingly  to the documentation [Interacting with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console):

  > **Caution**: The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
  > restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
  > serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
  > instance from any IP address. Anybody can connect to that instance if
  > they know the correct SSH key, username, project ID, zone, and
  > instance name. Use firewall rules to control access to your network
  > and specific ports.

If you weren't able to connect via serial console, try follow the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) section [Inspect the VM instance without shutting it down](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#inspect_vm) and inspect the disk of your VM on another VM. Same way you can transfer your data to another working VM instance.

Comment: Thank you, after checking  Logs on Serial port 1 i found filesystem corruption, so i have connect via Serial port and run `fsck /dev/sda1`. It repair disk and all woks fine now.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation.