# Can't SSH into my Instance : Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm encountering a problem whenever I'm trying to use the Web-SSH-Tool on GCP.
I haven't changed anything, it literally happened over night.
I've tired playing with the Firewall Rules,even added a new one, I've also restarted the instance, and done a reset - all to no avail.

This is the error message I get:

Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed
Code: 4010
Reason: destination read failed
You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.

Can anyone help me with that ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to connect to virtual machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035275/unable-to-connect-to-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 2):

**POSSIBLE CASE 1:** You have enabled ufw without proper permissions(I did in my earlier days)

If yes you need to add a startup-script in the instance by adding a metadata(by editing the instance)
with key `startup-script` and value

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo ufw disable
```

and now when you hard-reset(reset using the reset button in gcp) your VPS it should be ok.
and then when its ok you may remove the metadata.

**POSSIBLE CASE 2:** You have disabled the default-ssh in gcp vpc firewall

If this is the case, still need not worry, simply add a rule and allow port 22 and if you have trouble adding it then simply add tcp port 22 to a existing firewall rule created by default by GCP.

**POSSIBLE CASE 3:** You have done some changes in IAM that you lost access to gce.

***Warning: If you have not touched IAM , Donot edit the IAM unless you really know what you are doing, else unexpected things may occur.***

Make Sure you have your email in IAM with role as `owner`

Hope it helped.

**Last Not-so-magical Technique (Dirty Fix):**

***Warning: If you tried all the above and also tried your best to fix it by your own, but in case if nothing works then only do this.***

Create a new PROJECT in gcp and there you need to link the billing account and start over again fresh and everything will be fine.

I know this one is a horrible fix, and thats true , if nothing works and you start to feel you are having a lot of time wasted then ***only*** you should consider this fix.

Comment: u da real mvp, mate

Answer (score 1):

[Manav's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1036530/617646) is pretty broad and precise, and I'll just add some information in case you are running long/compute-heavy processes in a VM instance;
If that's your use case, try using [nohup](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiP7azfwPTuAhW5E7kGHZmMDSIQFjACegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Flinux.101hacks.com%2Funix%2Fnohup-command%2F&usg=AOvVaw1QGHuNqIRHN4PSMOKw6If4) and setting your processes as a background one. Say you're running a bash script, then you'd do

```
nohup yourScript.sh &
```

You can sleep tight and let your routines running for days without interruption - just watch out for charges :-)